# whenever i click the side navigation menu, the page gets scrolled towards right horizontally

Tags: css

i have a side navigation menu which refers to the sections towards right side of the page ,whenever i resize the window and click the menu , the page gets scrolled  horizonatally (scroll postion changing).making the content to overlap.  how to fix , i have used overflow:y:hidden option but it doesnt work for small screen size.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-link {
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: 9px;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="set" id="Set">
  <div class="content">
    <nav id="nav">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link"> href="#info" </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link">href="#section2" </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="main">
      <info ref='info' />
      <section2 ref="section2" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your code contains errors and is not complete (unclosed tags, etc.). Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There's nothing in your code. please create a code snippet of the working code

Comment: What is the `<info>` and the `<section2>` tag ? And the attribute `ref` ? Do you mean `href` ? There's also missing closing tags in your two `<a>` tags and missing `<div>` tags for the class **content** and **set**